# Unity3D Vuforia Camera Position in Real World Unit

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am using Vuforia and Unity3D to develop an application. For this, I need to get the camera position (x,y,z) in real world unit from an image target while tracking the image with a mobile phone. I was wondering if it is possible to get such position information in Vuforia . if Yes, any sample code would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you mwan the position relative to the image target in the world?

Comment: yes... position of mobile phone camera from the target image

Comment: does the MNM's answer work?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this.

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
public Transform target;
Camera camera;

void Start() {
    camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
}

void Update() {
    Vector3 screenPos = camera.WorldToScreenPoint(target.position);
    Debug.Log("target is " + screenPos.x + " pixels from the left");
}
}
```

What this does is 
Transforms position from world space into screen space.

Screenspace is defined in pixels. The bottom-left of the screen is (0,0); the right-top is (pixelWidth,pixelHeight). The z position is in world units from the camera.

May not be exactly what you want but its a starting point.

EDIT:
This returns world Space not local space so this should be exactly what you want

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject someObject;
public Vector3 thePosition;

void Start() {
    // Instantiate an object to the right of the current object
    thePosition = transform.TransformPoint(Vector3.right * 2);
    Instantiate(someObject, thePosition, someObject.transform.rotation);
}
}
```

Note that the returned position is affected by scale. Use Transform.TransformDirection if you are dealing with direction vectors. You can perform the opposite conversion, from world to local space using Transform.InverseTransformPoint.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply@MNM. Yes, this code is really helpful getting information from a target image as  this will give me target position in screen space. I was wondering if it is possible to get the target position in real world unit.

Comment: see my edits that I posted that should fix the issue your having